# how to correctly set destmodule (destination module) for D2D Multicast simulation

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am trying to simulate car to car communication within simulate using the D2D Multicast configuration.
However, I notice that no messages are sent between the cars directly during the simulation due to this error found in the simulation log:

```
** Event #4666  t=1.09  Highway.car[0].udpApp[0] (CbrSender, id=246)  on selfmsg initTraffic (omnetpp::cMessage, id=2592)
**INFO (CbrSender)Highway.car[0].udpApp[0]: 1.09CbrSender::initTraffic - destination 224.0.0.10 not found
INFO (CbrSender)Highway.car[0].udpApp[0]: 1.09CbrSender::initTraffic - the node will retry to initialize traffic in 0.01 seconds**
```

Destination module is set to NULL (see code reference below) hence, the destination is not found

```
    void CbrSender::initTraffic()
{
    std::string destAddress = par("destAddress").stringValue();
    cModule* destModule = getModuleByPath(par("destAddress").stringValue());
    EV<<"destModule:"<<destModule<<endl;
    if (destModule == NULL)
    {
        // this might happen when users are created dynamically
        EV << simTime() << "CbrSender::initTraffic - destination " << destAddress << " not found" << endl;
```

**Is this error due to dynamically created users? How can this be fixed?**

As mentioned in the readme.txt of the D2DMulticast, I have set the multicast cast group in demo.xml for UEs to receive the multicast message from the sender.

```
<multicast-group hosts="car[*]" interfaces="wlan" address="224.0.0.10"/>
```

The omnetpp.ini parameters are as follows :

```
[Config D2DMulticast]
### Enable D2D for the eNodeB and the UEs involved in direct communications ###
*.eNodeB*.d2dCapable = true
*.car[*].d2dCapable = true
**.amcMode = "D2D"

### Select CQI for D2D transmissions ###
# One-to-Many communications work with fixed CQI values only.
# Set the parameter **.usePreconfiguredTxParams and select the desired CQI using the parameter **.d2dCqi
**.usePreconfiguredTxParams = true
**.d2dCqi = ${cqi=7}

### Traffic configuration: one-to-many traffic between UEs (car[0] --> car[1..9]) ###
*.car[*].numUdpApps = 1

# Transmitter
*.car[0].udpApp[*].typename = "CbrSender"
*.car[0].udpApp[*].localPort = 3088+ancestorIndex(0) 
*.car[0].udpApp[*].startTime = uniform(0s,0.02s)
*.car[0].udpApp[*].destAddress = "224.0.0.10"          # IP address of the multicast group 
*.car[0].udpApp[*].destPort = 1000

# Receivers (they must belong to the above multicast group)
*.car[1].udpApp[*].typename = "CbrReceiver"
*.car[1].udpApp[*].localPort = 1000

# enrolled multicast groups must be set in the HostAutoConfigurator (instead of demo.xml), seperated by a single space character
*.car[*].configurator.mcastGroups = "224.0.0.10"
```

Comment: Steps to reproduce:
1. Simulte and veins 4.6 libraries are built using omnet++ 5.1.1 and inet 3.6.4 [link] (http://simulte.com/add_veins.html)
2. Use default configuration for sumo map(heterogeneous) and Highway.ned inside **simulte/simulations/cars/** directory.
3. Use _D2DMulticast_ config in run omnetpp.ini and run simulation in qtenv.
4. Check event logs in qtenv by filtering out for car[0].udpApp.

Comment: Also another important step is to add multicast group in demo.xml :
<multicast-group hosts="car[*]" interfaces="wlan" address="224.0.0.10"/>

Comment: Which software version of SimuLTE are you using?

Comment: simulte v0.9.1 as provided in the zip on the simulte webpage

Comment: The "add_veins" page you mentioned in the "steps to reproduce" asks you to download a different version, no?

Comment: Sorry for reporting wrong version, it is simulte v1.0.1 as mentioned in the version file of the zip

Comment: This is odd. Just to be sure, could you try out Instant Veins <http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/instant-veins/>? If you download a version that already includes SimuLTE, you'll have a complete, working environment and can check for differences to your setup.